# Error starting MongoDB error 111 connection refused

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I installed pymongo on my Fedora. But whenever i run the script it shows error 111 Connection refused. I tried the solution of deleting /var/mongo/mongodb/mongod.lock file , but this file doesn't exist. Cannot find my way out of this.

Comment: Maybe your mongodb server havn't started yet, you can check that by execute command `netstat -ntpl | grep mongo` on your mongodb server.

Comment: No output on running this command @Shawyeok .

Comment: It means your mongodb server haven't start. [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/)